# Ошибка при выполнении git push

Tags: git

Подскажите, что нужно сделать в такой ситуации. Я в гите не очень хорошо разбираюсь

```
    Removing public_html/wp-content/plugins/shopify-ecommerce-shopping-cart/assets/css/styles.css.map

    CONFLICT (modify/delete): public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/templates/archive.php deleted in HEAD and modified in efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c. Version efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c of public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/templates/archive.php left in tree.

    CONFLICT (modify/delete): public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/screenshot-5.png deleted in HEAD and modified in efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c. Version efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c of public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/screenshot-5.png left in tree.

    CONFLICT (modify/delete): public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/screenshot-4.png deleted in HEAD and modified in efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c. Version efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c of public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/screenshot-4.png left in tree.

    CONFLICT (modify/delete): public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/screenshot-3.png deleted in HEAD and modified in efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c. Version efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c of public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/screenshot-3.png left in tree.

    CONFLICT (modify/delete): public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/screenshot-2.png deleted in HEAD and modified in efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c. Version efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c of public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/screenshot-2.png left in tree.

    CONFLICT (modify/delete): public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/screenshot-1.png deleted in HEAD and modified in efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c. Version efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c of public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/screenshot-1.png left in tree.

    CONFLICT (modify/delete): public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/includes/class-amp-post-template.php deleted in HEAD and modified in efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c. Version efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c of public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/includes/class-amp-post-template.php left in tree.

    CONFLICT (modify/delete): public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/includes/class-amp-common-template.php deleted in HEAD and modified in efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c. Version efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c of public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/includes/class-amp-common-template.php left in tree.

    CONFLICT (modify/delete): public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/includes/class-amp-archive-template.php deleted in HEAD and modified in efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c. Version efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c of public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/includes/class-amp-archive-template.php left in tree.

    CONFLICT (modify/delete): public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/.gitignore deleted in HEAD and modified in efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c. Version efaf22b684d3a3075fefabb1487dd4447463f10c of public_html/wp-content/plugins/amp/.gitignore left in tree.

    Removing public_html/wp-content/plugins/accelerated-mobile-pages/includes/options/redux-core/assets/css/vendor/elusive-icons/scss/elusive-icons.css.map

    Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Comment: То, что и написано — fix conflicts. Про решение конфликтов навалом информации и в интернете вообще, и на этом сайте в частности

Comment: Судя по ошибкам это был не push

Comment: Что за народ, ну один уже написал как правильно сделать, спасибо. А второму принципиально нужно выделиться, легче стало от минуса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решил вопрос таким способом:**

git rm --cached . -r

git reset --hard 988634c

git push origin HEAD --force

я вернулся на предыдущий коммит, где все было нормально, и после этого сделал все правильно

Comment: Для универальности: вместо точного указания коммита можно использовать HEAD, HEAD~1, HEAD~2 и так далее. Во-вторых, `--force` не всегда приемлем в командах. В-третьих, ответ Kovadim правильнее и универсальнее, но если вам помогло именно это - можете поставить галку через два дня на свой ответ.

Comment: Да мне вообще фиолетово, я в начале вопроса написал, что я в гите не особо разбираюсь, во вторых я не сижу тут сутками, и забыл что можно ответить на свой же вопрос. И тут начали яйцами закидывать. Какой смысл критиковать человека и делать замечания, если можно просто подсказать? Или так проще жить? Под ответом Kovadim я написал, что делал уже так, как он писал, мой вопрос таким способом не решился

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно решить конфликты. У Вас есть два вида файлов, для них по разному решаются конфликты.

Первое - это картинки. С ними план такой - открыть, посмотреть. Если картинка правильная - значит ок, если нет, найти правильную (в Вашем случае так будет проще). После этого сделать `git add <этот файл>`.

Второе - это php файлы (и любые другие текстовые). Тут нужно по очереди открывать их в редакторе и искать строку с семи знаков равно. Выше и ниже от этого куска увидите символы `<<<<<<<` и `>>>>>>>`. Эти символы выделяют спорный момент. Его нужно руками отредактировать до получения правильного  результата (и только Вы знаете, как выглядит правильный результат). И в конце конечно сделать git add. Всегда убеждайтесь в том, что не оставили кусков с `=======` (то есть, сам конфликт).

Также могут оказаться файлы, которые в результате мерджа были удалены (они в git status) так и помечены. Если согласны с этим, просто согласитесь с этим, выполнив `git rm <имя файла>`.

Когда все файлы будут обработаны и добавлены (git status это подскажет), можно сделать commit как обычно.

[Пример, как фиксить конфликты](https://githowto.com/ru/resolving_conflicts).

Comment: Я делал так, хз, не получилось. Искал вчера в инете, пробовал решить, но после всех неудач пришлось обратиться сюда. Сейчас снова буду пробовать.

Comment: В общем я решил свою проблему, обновил содержимое вопроса

Comment: @eugene_v Ответы - в ответы: вам не нужно обновлять содержимое вопроса, вам просто нужно написать свой ответ, возможно кому-то пригодится.